# showWindow but wait for window to load?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two .xib files, MainMenu and PreferenceMenu. I set the File's Owner of PreferenceMenu to be a subclass of `NSWindowController`, so that I can modify how the window is opened, modified, etc.

Normally I open PreferenceMenu through IB, sending the `showWindow:` action to the Preferences Controller object. This has been working fine, and the window has been opening flawlessly. I also implemented `NSTabView` and `NSToolBar` in my PreferenceMenu as different tabs house different preferences.

Anyways, I now have to prompt the user if they want to open up the PreferenceMenu after first loading the application. My process is check to see if a `NSUserDefaults` key is set, then prompts and sets the key if it isn't. If the returned `NSAlert` button is a specific button, I then open up PreferenceMenu and switch to the correct tab.

The gist of this process is to:

1. Import `CCPreferencesController.h` in `CCAppDelegate.h`
2. Create a `strong` reference to the `CCPreferencesController` window (for ARC)
3. Prompt with `NSAlert`, and if returned button is correct, run the following:

   ```
   self.windowController = [[CCPreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"];
   [self.windowController showWindow:self];
   ```
4. Import `CCAppDelegate.h` in `CCPreferencesController.m`
5. Deal with the `NSAlert` response in `CCPreferencesController.m`:

   ```
   - (void)showWindow:(id)sender{
       if ([CCAppDelegate class] == [sender class]){
           [self openLogin];
       }
       [super showWindow:sender];
   }
   ```
6. Switch the `TabView` in the `openLogin` method.

This more of less works fine, **except `showWindow` is called before the window's contents have actually loaded**. This means that calling `self.toolbar`, `self.tabView`, etc. returns `NULL`. My solution to this is to simply use a timer to wait for the elements to load, but this is nowhere near elegant.

**My question, therefore**, is how can I avoid having to use a delay, and instead have my `openLogin` method get called on `showWindow` but wait for the window's contents to be loaded?

I'm also 99% sure that my code is awful, including how I'm importing .h files and subclassing File's Owner, so any tips to make this better are greatly appreciated.

---

For those who want to see the code in more detail, here are the relevant parts

**CCAppDelegate.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "CCPreferencesController.h"

@class WebView;

@interface CCAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate, NSSharingServiceDelegate>

@property (strong) CCPreferencesController *windowController;
...

@end
```

**CCAppDelegate.m:**

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame{
    bool loginPrompted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loginPrompted"];
    if (!loginPrompted){
        NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Login"
                                         defaultButton:@"Login"
                                       alternateButton:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButton:nil
                             informativeTextWithFormat:@"Would you like to login to enable voting?"];
        // Display alert
        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
            // Return focus to window
            [[alert window] orderOut:self];
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"loginPrompted"];
            [prefs synchronize];
            if (returnCode == 1){
                self.windowController = [[CCPreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"];
                [self.windowController showWindow:self];
            }
        }];

    }

}
```

**CCPreferencesController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CCPreferencesController : NSWindowController {}

...

@end
```

**CCPreferencesController.m**

```
#import "CCPreferencesController.h"
#import "CCAppDelegate.h"

@implementation CCPreferencesController

- (id)init{
    if(self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"]) {}
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    ... 
    [self.toolbar setSelectedItemIdentifier:@"general"];
}

- (void)showWindow:(id)sender{
    if ([CCAppDelegate class] == [sender class]){
        [self openLogin];
    }
    [super showWindow:sender];
}

// This is gross
- (void)openLogin{
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 0.1);
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.toolbar setSelectedItemIdentifier:@"tab"];
        [self.tabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];
        NSRect frame = [self.window frame];
        frame.size.height += 55;
        frame.origin.y -= 55;
        [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you have the window outlet of File's Owner in PreferencesMenu.xib hooked up to the top-level window in that xib?

Comment: @stevesliva Yes, I do

Comment: "except showWindow is called before the window's contents have actually loaded." -- this seems to be incorrect.  You call "openLogin" before [super showWindow]...  openLogin is called before you show the window... I wonder if it is not loaded at that point.   You might override windowDidLoad to invoke openLogin regardless. (This is what the class documentation suggests)

Comment: @stevesliva using `windowDidLoad` seems to be like the way to go, but how can I make sure that the request is coming from the alert and not form the menu? `showWindow` at least has the `sender` id to query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the other options, in my opinion, you ought to just do this:

```
        if (returnCode == 1){
            self.windowController = [[CCPreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferenceMenu"];
            [self.windowController showWindow:self];
            __weak CCAppDelegate* weakSelf = self;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf.windowController openLogin];
           }
```

And this:

```
- (void)openLogin{
    [self.toolbar setSelectedItemIdentifier:@"tab"];
    [self.tabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];
    NSRect frame = [self.window frame];
    frame.size.height += 55;
    frame.origin.y -= 55;
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

You are already instructing the WC to do something.  It's not out of line to instruct it to show a particular tab, if the WC provides a public method to do such a thing.

It is essentially what I do when a user clicks a notification.  I show the window, and have the window controller react tho what's in the userInfo dictionary in the notification on the next runloop iteration.

[edit] -- now schedules openLogin on the runloop with dispatch_async

Comment: This is much, much cleaner. I guess I was overthinking it, cause it makes much more sense to call `showWindow` then `openLogin` in the same method. The one thing I had to do which wasn't explicitly stated was make `openLogin` a public method, but other than that it works perfectly.

Comment: One relatively large problem, however... if I use this to open up the window, it will do so, but if I attempt to open up the preferences menu via the menubar, it will open up two instances of PreferenceMenu. Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea.  It shouldn't be the code here, as far as I'd guess, which makes me suspect a Nib issue, but it's easy to always suspect IB.

Comment: I think it's because I'm opening a different instance of the menu from the alert, and a different from the menu item. I could check a variable when I load the window, then reset it when the window is closed?

Comment: Do you mean you have an application menu in each nib?  Responder chain issue?  Not my forte...

Comment: No I mean my main window which opens the preference window via the menubar item. It calls the `showWindow:` method. Except if I load the menu with `[self.windowController showWindow:self]`, then open it via the menubar item, it creates a new preference menu instead of not opening as another one (the one from this answer) is already present.

Comment: By "menu" you mean a preferences window/panel?  Are you creating a whole new WC?  My showPreferencesPanel method checks to see if the preferencesWC is nil, and creates it if so, but does showWindow every time I select the menu item.  showWindow numerous times should be fine.  It's alloc+init I'd be careful of.

Comment: That was my problem! I kept allocating it every time instead of just showing it every time. Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: @Daij-Djan, If showWindow is using the runloop, then use dispatch_async on openLogin, no?

Comment: @stevesliva, what for do you use `dispatch_async`?  I believe showing window is straightforward and you don't need to shuffle `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_after` around the code.  I.e. you don't need any delays whatsoever.

Comment: I'm still uncertain on that point, too... been meaning to investigate it.  I use bindings, and *they* have been causing seemingly synchronous code to complete asynchronously.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous) for more detail.  I'm fairly certain that I need to schedule selecting GUI elements if some bindings are operating asynchronously, so that the binding propagation can happen first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd *not* go this way but maybe it is right in your situation because you do it bloc kingly but before you call showWindow you could force load the window. just call `self.window` before you call `super showWindow`

NOTE that calling a getter to achieve side-effects is also far from clean!

It'd be best to move the code that needs the window in something like windowDidLoad or so

### MAYBE

```
@implementation MyWindowController {
    NSDictionary *_options;
}

- (void)showWindow:(id)sender{
    if ([CCAppDelegate class] == [sender class]){
        _options = @{@"Login": @YES};
    } else {
        _options = nil; 
    }

    if(self.isWindowLoaded) {
        [self applyOptions];
    }
    [super showWindow:sender];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [self applyOptions];
}

- (void)applyOptions {
    if([_options[@"Login"] boolValue]) {
        //if logged in ... blablabla
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? I would have to call `self.window` on the `PreferenceMenu` within `CCAppDelegate.m`, correct? Or call it from within `showWindow`?

Comment: whatever you like.. goes before super showWindow. please be aware that using a property to achieve side effects is also not very clean

Comment: Can you recommend a way to restructure all this to avoid these dirty workarounds?

Comment: move stuff that needs the window to windowDidLoad maybe?!

Comment: How would I pass a parameter to windowDidLoad so that I know the request is coming from the alert and not an arbitrary opening of the preference menu? Because with `showWindow` I at least have the `sender` id to query...

Comment: no blocking or so ... again: opinion based but id go this way. save what you need when asked to show and then keep an internal 'state'

Comment: I ended up going with @stevesliva's code as it seemed to be the most straightforward. I appreciate all of your help though.

Comment: you could have taken sapsais then -- it is nearly the same

Answer (score 0):

What if you call `[super showWindow:sender]` before `[self openLogin]`?  Like

```
- (void)showWindow:(id)sender {
    [super showWindow:sender];
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[CCAppDelegate class]]) {
        [self openLogin];
    }
}
```

Added:

Sorry, my suggestion to move `[super showWindow:sender]` before `[self openLogin]` doesn't explain your problems.  `self.toolbar` and `self.tabView` are `nil` because they are `IBOutlet`s and outlets aren't set until the corresponding nib file is loaded.  The delay is just a way to wait until nib file is loaded and you admit yourself it's a fishy approach.  Another solution is to load nib before calling `[self openLogin]` and I've offered to call `-showWindow:` because `-showWindow:` indirectly loads nib if it isn't loaded already.  I strongly encourage you to add breakpoints in `-[CCPreferencesController awakeFromNib]` and `-[CCPreferencesController windowDidLoad]`.  Thus you can see in debugger when nib file is loaded and when `IBOutlet`s are ready to be used.

I don't know anything about `-[NSWindowController showWindow:]` scheduling something on the runloop.  Unfortunately, @Daij-Djan hasn't provided any details about what exactly is scheduled on the runloop.  @Daij-Djan has suggested to perform `-openLogin` actions in `-windowDidLoad`, but I see a sequence `before_showWindow:, windowDidLoad, after_showWindow:`.  I make a conclusion that nib is loaded immediately, not scheduled on the runloop.  That's why it is safe to call `-openLogin` without any delays.

Once again, I encourage you to check yourself in debugger how nib file is loaded.  It is better to check it yourself, than rely on somebody's words.

The answer to question how to avoid using delay: call `-openLogin` after window is loaded and in this case call `-openLogin` after `-showWindow:` because it causes nib loading.

Comment: that would introduce a race condition and would very likely work 100% with the way it is currently implemented but this is really dirty

Comment: Yeah it works, but @Daij-Djan, can you explain why this is frowned upon?

Comment: you call a method and rely on the fact that the drawing of the window will only happen AFTER your alert because till after the alert you block

Comment: it is like telling a guy to start running and he has already begun moving his legs but you hold 'em tight for a few seconds... blocking him

Comment: and if he were just too fast for you you couldn't block him ... here you relly on the knowledge that the window is 'slow' to appear

Comment: So it's essentially the same thing as putting an arbitrary delay on it as well, right? Because it could have failed to draw before the delay has finished...

Comment: a bit better because the delay will ALWAYS be big enough with the current implementation of apple's window! but that doesn't make it pretty -- but thats opinion-based I'd say

Comment: @Daij-Djan, sorry, I don't understand you. How calling `-[super showWindow:]` before `-openLogin` does introduce a race condition? Are you talking about delay in `-openLogin`? Because my suggested fix doesn't require this delay.

Comment: it works that way because showWindow schedules stuff on the runloop that is advanced after your modal alert

Comment: How modal alert affects `-[CCPreferencesController showWindow:]` if  `-showWindow:` is called in alert completion handler? And what exactly `-showWindow:` schedules on the runloop? Because at least window is loaded immediately. I.e. I see `before_showWindow:, windowDidLoad, after_showWindow:`.