# How can I determine if Apple methods are asynchronous?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging, asynchronous, cocoa-bindings

I'm binding an NSArrayController to a managedObjectContext with mainQueueConcurrency.

All that I want is to do is modify the sort properties the arrangedObjects with my own function and then call `rearrangeObjects` and then select some objects.

But it's looking like `rearrangeObjects` doesn't execute synchronously.

So how can I prove that, one way or the other?

This works:

```
[self.myArrayController rearrangeObjects];

// Async needed -- I believe rearrange calls a fetch, which is async
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.myArrayController setSelectedObjects:anArray];
});
```

Minus the `dispatch_async`, it doesn't work.  The selection doesn't happen.

I'm fairly convinced that like `fetch` on an NSArrayController, <strike>`rearrangeObjects` is scheduling itself on the next runloop iteration.</strike>**  So how do I prove that?  I can throw breakpoints in there and examine the array controller, etc etc.  And I have, and I suspect that's what's happening.

But is there some debugging trick which would just make it obvious "Eureka! This line of code's launching an asynchronous operation" ??

** It was cocoa bindings that's doing something asynchronously.  Of course.  rearrangeObjects just triggers it.

Comment: I have a similar concern about NSWindowController's `showWindow`

Comment: just a thought ... add a log line of the array and set a breakpoint on it (after the call to rearrange), set a breakpoint on the `rearrangeObjects` call, get an unsorted array, run the application untill it gets to the rearrange call, step over it, pause the main thread, resume the application execution (with the main thread paused), then pause application and resume the main thread execution, get to the log line and print the array. is it sorted? if yes then the rearrange happened on another thread.

Comment: Thanks-- I didn't realize you could pause by thread, and I experimented a little.  But I suspect this is all in the main thread dispatch queue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to catch `rearrangeObjects` invoking `dispatch_async_f` (through bindings) by breaking just before the suspect line of code and enabling **symbolic breakpoints on the GCD dispatch_async functions:**

[image: symbolic breakpoints on dispatch_async*]

And, sure enough, the `dispatch_async_f` symbolic breakpoint stopped on the `rearrangeObjects` line:

[image: breakpoint activated on rearrangeObjects]

Comment: I have learned sooooo much about what the framework is actually doing, by using symbolic breakpoints.

Comment: BTW in a couple of days you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @matt -- it's a new trick for me!  Found it after sleeping on this and googling this morning.  But I did think, "wow, this will be *very* useful."

Comment: but is it invoked on a thread other then the main thread, or is it just scheduled for later execution on the main thread?

Comment: @DanShelly, I don't know that for certain.  I wonder if the binding implementation is using `perform_block` on the MOC.. which is mainQueue, but it gets run after my subsequent code.  Regardless of the thread, something is getting run after my code.