# How is NSTableView Content Sorted After Array Controller Add?

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

After adding a managed object in array controller class, the bound table view 'places' it into the correct date sorted order.

However, as the table view is building it's rows, the new object has been placed at the bottom of the array controller's content array using:

**Edit:**  Solution: Don't use the array controller's `content`. The issue was in:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    ....
    //  originally
    NSManagedObject *ci = [[self.arrayController content] objectAtIndex:row];
    // should be: (note arrangedObjects replacing content)
    NSManagedObject *ci = [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
    ....
}
```

The image below shows an example of the placement. Console output from within `-tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:` at left (from original code above) and ordering in the table view on right. LHR is the new object (notice date order ascending).

[image]

Tried:

1. Saving the moc right after adding newObject
2. Calling Array Controller's arrangeObjects method
3. Attempting to manually `setSortDescriptors`
4. Binding the table view's selection index to the array controller (for grins)

This is also messing up the `selectedRow` even though the row with LHR is selected in the table view right after adding. The only way to correct the array controller's order is to manually sort the column.

How can the array controller's content be in sync with the table view? Even more, why might they not be in the same order?

Comment: Does your array controller use lazy fetching?

Comment: @sbooth  No, lazy fetching is unchecked.

Comment: OK, I've experienced sorting issues before with lazy fetching which is why I asked.

Comment: @sbooth Interestingly, checking 'uses lazy fetching', causes LHR to be the fourth item in of both the table view and array controller's arrangedObjects. I don't think this is the solution, because the tableview does not sort by date, until manual column header selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array controller "arranges" its content. It does this by calling its `-arrangeObjects:` method. The default implementation filters the contents using the array controller's `filterPredicate` and then sorts it using its `sortDescriptors`. A subclass could override that method to arrange the content differently.

The arranged contents can be accessed using the `arrangedObjects` property. ***This*** is what corresponds to rows in the table view. So, you should always use this if you're indexing by a table row. For example:

```
NSManagedObject *ci = [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
```

The array controller's `sortDescriptors` may be set via bindings (e.g. if the table view's `sortDescriptors` binding is bound to the array controller). Depending on how you set up the table view bindings, this may be automatic. For `NSCell`-based table views, you typically bind the table columns `value` binding and don't bind the table views bindings. In that case, the table view automatically binds its `content`, `selectionIndexes`, and `sortDescriptors` bindings to the same controller as its columns. For view-based table views, you typically don't bind table columns and have to bind those table view bindings explicitly if you want them bound.

You can also set the array controller's `sortDescriptors` programmatically.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. Essentially, `-arrangeObjects:` is empty, yet sorting is working on initial load and column headers selection. I changed to using `self.arrayController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row` as you suggested. Still, the 'arrangement' after adding is the same. To keep sorting working as now, can you offer what should be in `-arrangedObjects:` ? (see edit)

Comment: Huh? What do you mean `-arrangeObjects:` is empty? Did you override that? Or did you mean `arrangedObjects`, which is different (the first uses the verb "arrange", the second uses the adjective "arrange**d**"; the first has a colon because it takes a parameter, the second has no colon because it's a property getter). You should generally not override `-arrangeObjects:` unless you have a reason to do so. When are you querying `[self.arrayController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row]`? Perhaps the sort descriptors or content haven't been set, yet?

Comment: `-arrangeObjects` is empty. (used it for console output)  `-arrangedObjects has not been overridden. See edit 2 regarding an attempt with the later.

Comment: You should not be overriding any methods of `NSArrayController`. I'm still not sure what you're talking about when you say `-arrangeObjects` is empty. There's no such method as `-arrangeObjects`; there's `-arrangeObjects:` with a colon and `-arrangedObjects` with a "d". Second, are you saying it's returning an empty array? Or are you saying you've implemented some method and left the implementation empty (no code)? I suspect your problem is that you're querying the array controller before it has any content at all. Array controllers don't fetch from Core Data until after `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: My mistake. Using `-arrangeObjects:` for printing the list of managed objects in console. Not using `-arrangedObjects`. So, if I don't override any array controller methods, the original question still exists. How can the lists be in the same order in the table view and in arrangedObjects? (The original question show them ordered differently.)

Comment: No, the question showed the table and *`content`* (not `arrangedObjects`) in a different order. `arrangedObjects` will be in the same order as the table view. That's *how* the table view got sorted in the first place. (As an aside, if you overrode `-arrangeObjects:`, I hope you called through to `super` and returned what it returned.)

Comment: Selecting this as answer because it corrected my use of `-content`, clarifying that I should have been calling `-arrangedObjects` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `rearrangeObjects` on the NSArrayController and then doing the selection you need subsequent to that in a `dispatch_async` block.  It's maddening, but some of the bindings are deferred to the next runloop turn, so you can't simply add an object, call rearrangeObjects, and select the new object in synchronous code.  You have to use GCD to schedule things

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous) for more discussion.  It's is *the exact* same issue.  Adding an object and trying to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Auto Rearrange Content option of the Array Controller made it for me.

[image]