# NSTableview refresh asynchronous loading of data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I've got an NSTableView hooked up with an NSArrayController in XIB. In my app I'm loading data asynchronously and continuously call `[_arrayController addObject:someNewObject]`. I had expected this to update the NSTableView, instead I have to switch the app between foreground/background in order to see the updates.

So I tried to let the NSTableView refresh itself upon every addObject by adding one of following statements

- `[_tableView reloadData]`
- `[_tableView setNeedsDisplay:YES]`
- `[_tableView display]`

However, the NSTableView doesn't refresh itself when it's running in the foreground.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:` NSArrayController method?

Comment: The addObject should work, I've just tried with a sandbox project, difference there is I'm operating on NSString and not an arbitrary app domain object. So not sure if something has to be done regarding the bindings.

Comment: Correction, it works with a app domain object. I tried to use dispatch_after:..: which works, this led me to think that these updates must be executed on the main tread (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rearrangeObjects` on the AC, but be aware that [it's not synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous) either.

So, `addObject` then `rearrangeObjects` then `dispatch_async` to execute any code that's dependent on the tableView displaying the new object.  Examples in the linked question/answer.

Comment: I did the following: dispatch async the addObject on the main queue. Not sure atm if this will cause trouble if the connection is slow. But that will be problem for the future. I will accept your answer on the basis of the dispatch_async hint :).

Comment: Yeah, I assumed the addObject was already on the main thread.  dispatch_async is certainly useful for getting it there.