# NSArrayController sortDescriptors is not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, nsarraycontroller, nssortdescriptor

I'm have a NSArrayController (A) bind it to another NSArrayController (B) and I'm trying to sort the NSArrayController (B) but is not working.

Here is my code:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *bSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                           initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    self.arrayControllerB.sortDescriptors = @[bSortDescriptor];
```

Does any of you knows why the NSSortDescriptor is not working?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: How are your array controllers bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change the sort descriptors, you need to invoke `rearrangeObjects` on the array controller.  And then schedule whatever code you want to manipulate the sorted contents with `dispatch_async`.

Based on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous).  Hope this helps.