# How to store and restore NSTableView selection using NSArrayController bindings?

Tags: core-data, selection, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I've created a simple master detail application using two `CoreData` entities, two `NSTableView`s and two `NSArrayController`s to connect everything through bindings and not write code. I want to remember and restore the selected detail row for every master row.

The master entity has a title and multiple details (one-to-many relation):

```swift
class Master: NSManagedObject {
}

// Generated
extension Master {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var details: NSSet?
}
```

The details entity just has a title:

```swift
class Detail: NSManagedObject {
}

// Generated
extension Master {
    @NSManaged var title: String?
}
```

The first table view shows all master entities, the second table view shows all detail entities from the selected master entity in the first table. Both table views are configured to only allow single selection:

[image: Simple master detail application]

What I now would like to do is storing the index of the selected detail in the master entity. When the same master entity gets selected again, the second table view should automatically restore that selection and select the same detail again.

For the sake of ease I've added a simple `selectionIndexes: NSIndexSet` property to the `Master` entity. I've then bound this property to the details NSArrayController's selection indexes property:

[image: Binding selection indexes]

Having this selection indexes binding actually stores the selected details index but some Cocoa code resets the selection to empty when the same master entity is selected again. This said the stored selection is overwritten with an empty selection.

`Avoid Empty Selection` and `Preserve Selection` are disable to avoid having NSArrayController selecting an item automatically if there's no item selected or always trying to select the same item again whenever its content changes (that's not what I want because different master entities might have details with the same title).

I've inspected the `get` and `set` calls to the `selectionIndexes` property such as:

```swift
class Master: NSManagedObject {

    var _selection = NSMutableIndexSet()
    var selectionIndexes: NSIndexSet {
        get {
            print("get", _selection)
            return _selection
        }
        set(selection) {
            _selection.removeAllIndexes()
            _selection.addIndexes(selection)
            print("set", _selection)
            //print(NSThread.callStackSymbols())
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the call log:

**Selecting the the 3rd detail of the first master entity:**

```
set [number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (2)]
get [number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (2)]
```

**Selecting another master entity:**

```
get (no indexes)
```

**And then selecting the first master entity again:**

```
get [number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (2)]
set (no indexes)
get (no indexes)
```

As you can see it first restores index `2` (the 3rd detail entity), but then assigns `(no indexes)`. Why is `selectionIndexes` re-assigned at this point? Here's the call stack of the last `set` call:

```
"0   SelectionTest                       0x00000001000029fd _TFC13SelectionTest6Masters16selectionIndexesCSo10NSIndexSet + 797",
"1   SelectionTest                       0x00000001000026ca _TToFC13SelectionTest6Masters16selectionIndexesCSo10NSIndexSet + 58",
"2   Foundation                          0x00007fff9d2a6c13 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 148",
"3   AppKit                              0x00007fff9c9f09ae -[NSArrayController _setMultipleValue:forKeyPath:atIndex:] + 208",
"4   Foundation                          0x00007fff9d25d80f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 287",
"5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9c88a72e -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 411",
"6   AppKit                              0x00007fff9c88a53c -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 248",
"7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9ca958c3 -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _updateSelectionIndexes:] + 226",
"8   AppKit                              0x00007fff9ca95ab0 -[NSControllerConfigurationBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 111",
"9   Foundation                          0x00007fff9d255a53 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 379",
"10  Foundation                          0x00007fff9d25fd7a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 1127",
"11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c6e57d8 -[NSController _notifyObserversForKeyPath:change:] + 206",
"12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c74242b -[NSArrayController didChangeValuesForArrangedKeys:objectKeys:indexKeys:] + 126",
"13  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c74208f -[NSArrayController _selectObjectsAtIndexesNoCopy:avoidsEmptySelection:sendObserverNotifications:forceUpdate:] + 584",
"14  Foundation                          0x00007fff9d23c178 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 424",
"15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c88a72e -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 411",
"16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c88a53c -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 248",
"17  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c868931 -[NSTableBinder tableView:didChangeToSelectedRowIndexes:] + 138",
"18  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c868857 -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableView:didChangeToSelectedRowIndexes:] + 153",
"19  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c728504 -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 119",
"20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c6f9723 -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 424",
"21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c881a15 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 5358",
"22  AppKit                              0x00007fff9cd83d1d -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322",
"23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9cd84fad -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212",
"24  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c6dd735 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517",
"25  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c6d9e49 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540",
"26  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c60d03a -[NSApplication run] + 796",
"27  AppKit                              0x00007fff9c58f520 NSApplicationMain + 1176",
"28  SelectionTest                       0x0000000100004d07 main + 87",
"29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff892705ad start + 1",
"30  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3"
```

The obvious question now is: How can I make NSArrayController store and restore the selected details index into its master entity without having somebody else overwriting it?

Comment: One dirty hack is to reject `selection`s in the `selectIndexes`' setter if its empty. But that prevents from intentionally assigning an empty selection. I would rather like to understand why an empty selection is assigned at all and how to prevent it.

Comment: What are the selectionIndexes on the detail table bound to? Not the detail AC, right?  Regardless of the exact bindings, I would not be surprised if you have to unbind the selection in the detail table, set it, and then bind it.  [It is not easy to do this sort of thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous/23789279#23789279).

Comment: `selectionIndexes` of the detail table view are not bound. But if bound to the details array controller's `selectionIndexes` the selection will be reset to empty the same as if it's not bound.

Comment: Right, I was wondering if you were binding the detail selection to the selectionIndexes keypath of the data model object that's selected in the master AC.  And in that light, I'm not sure I follow why you'd be binding the selected object's selectionIndexes to the master AC's selection.  You seemingly want to bind the selected master object's selectionIndexes to the detail AC's selection.  You have to save and restore the detail selection, not the master selection.

Comment: Yes, the  detail selection is bound to a key path of the master entity. Again, it works but Cocoa is emptying that bound property. Feel free to clone the project to see by yourself. It's all set up. Thank you for caring!

Comment: Please don't get confused by the key path name. It's also called `selectionIndexes` but it refers to the model's property name (not the array controller) specified with a getter and setter in the question post.