# NSOutlineView viewForTableColumn EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1)` intermittently. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with this exception for hours but I have not been able to get to the bottom of it. The problem is that XCode doesn't really tell why it's crashing.

I have `All Objective-C Exceptions` set up with `po $arg1` but the crash pointer still points to `AppDelegate`. Just to give you guys more info of what I am doing, I am creating dashboard with a pretty customized `NSOutlineView` that calls `reloadData` pretty frequently (every 5 seconds). The `dataSource` also gets updated before `reloadData` is called. I have suspicion that this concurrent updating of data and redisplaying it might be the issue but I am still not 100%.

When it crashes, it points to `class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate`.

The stackframe looks like:

[image]

When I click on frame 1, I get:

[image]

And the debug navigator

[image]

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous)?  I found that if you are using bindings, some of the Cocoa API methods do not complete within one runloop -- that is to say, when you call something like `reloadData` you can't assume it's concurrent.  It may well return without completing, and subsequent lines of your code are being called temporally before `reloadData` completes because it's using `dispatch_async` internally.  You can try to fix by using your `async` calls after `reloadData`

Comment: Thanks steve. I ended up changing my data structure and instead of doing `self.data = newData`, I update each object's primititives (int, string, etc) inside the collection. I still couldn't figure out why it was crashing..... but I haven't seen the crash since I changed the updating of data source to object update (no more setting to new collection).