# Use cocoa bindings and threads

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, cocoa-bindings

I have a few labels bound to a few variables that are modified in other threads via GCD.
Now I've read that cocoa bindings are not thread safe but my app is running fine (the UI updates when the values of the variables are updated in a background thread)

Would it be the correct way to do the calculations in the background thread and if I need to change the variable value make this via

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync() {
   self.variable = newValue
}
```

?
If cocoa bindings are not thread safe, why I never encountered any crash because of a "read" of the bound UI element while the value was written by a background process?

What is the preferred way to have a value bound to a UI element (via cocoa bindings) and also modify it by async threads?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you update your thread immediately, but the update of the value in the main thread gets scheduled by the framework.  Even if it's all one thread, bindings aren't necessarily synchronous.  You could set a breakpoint just before the line updating the variable, and then when the program is parked there, set symbolic breakpoints on the GCD dispatch functions.  You might see the bindings code call `dispatch_async` for you.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773827/how-can-i-determine-if-apple-methods-are-asynchronous).  Sorry, ObjC and not Swift.

Comment: @stevesliva KVO and bindings are synchronous. The visual update of controls isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you modify an object that is observed by Cocoa bindings, you should do so only on the main thread, and GCD dispatching the modification to the main thread is a good enough way to do that.

Yes, your app probably works fine most of the time, but that is likely luck based and not actually correct. The problem is that Cocoa bindings are based on Key Value Observation, and KVO notifications are posted on the thread that causes the mutation.

It’s also a complexity problem. As long as your app is relatively simple and fast, there’s much less chance of two threads running afoul of one another. Imagine when your app gets more complex and computationally intensive... and a problem crops up... but by this point you might have hundreds of places where you’re modifying bound properties from multiple threads. It’ll save you grief in the long run to just follow the rules. Use the main thread for updating bound to objects and try to keep bound properties to immutable, value-semantic types.

Comment: "try to keep bound properties to immutable, value-semantic types" why this? I bound a few labels to a mutable dictionary values (had to set it to @objc dynamic) and updated this dictionary values through threads quite often and I never (over years) had any crash here.

Comment: @MikeNathas - that comment is in the same ballpark with "I've been cleaning my gun this way for years and haven't shot myself yet!" The fact that one *can* do something doesn't imply that it's *bright* to do it. You might do it a thousand times with no problems, and then on that thousand and first time you do something trivially different (or worse, one of your teammates does), and find yourself with half a month of debugging trying to find what went wrong. Just sayin'...

Comment: Restricting bindings to immutable value-semantic types is not strictly necessary (and something, somewhere has to be mutable for the value to ever change) but using immutable, value-semantic types eliminates one possible path for particularly insidious and hard-to-debug errors. It’s a best practice more than a “rule” per se.

Comment: Also not sure what to think about this as binding to a immutable value makes no sense (I can simply add a fixed label instead)

Comment: Yeah. What I'm saying is that the values in your mutable dictionary should be immutable. i.e. Use `NSString` and not `NSMutableString`. If something else changes the mutable string, your binding will almost certainly *not* update.