# Swift: Thread-safe dictionary access via cocoa-bindings

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, cocoa-bindings

I have a class and I need to bind a few NSTextFields to some values of a dictionary that will be changed by a thread.

```
class Test: NSObject {
  @objc dynamic var dict : [String:Int] = [:]

  let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

  func changeValue() {
    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        self.dict["Key1"] = Int.random(in: 1..<100)
    }
  }

    func readValue() -> Int? {
        queue.sync {
            return self.dict["Key1"]
        }
    }

}
```

As far as I understood this is the way to do (so not accessing the variable directly but through a func that handles the queue.

But what when I try to bind a NSTextField to "Key1" of the dict using cocoa bindings?
Binding to the variable "dict" directly works in my tests but I'm not sure (I'm quite sure it isn't) if this is thread safe. 
What would be the correct way to do this?

Edit:
This code example looks legit but fails for some reason

```
class Test: NSObject {

    var _dict : [String:Int] = ["Key1":1]
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

    @objc dynamic var dict:[String:Int] {
        get {
            queue.sync { return self._dict }
        }
        set {
            queue.async(flags: .barrier) { self._dict = newValue }
        }
    }

    func changeValue() {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            // This change will not be visible in the bound object
            self._dict["Key1"] = Int.random(in: 1..<100)
            // This causes a crash
            self.dict = ["Key1":2]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No you can't bind to the variable dict. That circumvents everything your class achieves. The stored property should be private. You can expose a public `@objc dynamic` computed property which does the synchronization and reads/writes the stores property

Comment: Of course I can (technically) - you probably mean "you shouldn't". But what do you mean with "computed property"? When I have to create a var for each key I can just skip using a dictionary.

Comment: No, I mean you *should* expose a public `@objc dyanmic` computed property. Rename `dict` to `var _dict: [String: Int]`, and introduce an `@objc dynamic var dict: [String: Int] { get { ... } set { ... } }`, where the getter and setter use the same logic as `changeValue()` and `readValue()` to access `_dict` in a safe way. Then delete the functions, since you won't need them anymore.

Comment: This sounds legit but fails in this case as a change to the underlying _dict dictionary will not be visible in the bound textfield and a change in the dict variable will cause a crash (see exited post for code example)

Comment: Interesting, maybe cocoa bindings have an expectation that value changes are synchronous

Comment: See [Use cocoa bindings and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459408/use-cocoa-bindings-and-threads)

Comment: @Willeke: The solution suggested in this thread does not work in this case. Moving all code that directly changes dict to the main thread will cause a "most likely because the value for the key "dict" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent" error.